# Printing list items within a specific format

Tags: python

I have a list containing:

```
lst = [10,20,30,40]
```

and i want to print it in a form as such:

```
output: 10 --> 20 --> 30 --> 40
```

i tried writing:

```
print("output: " + "-->".join(lst))
```

but I'm getting an error saying str format required. Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: You want to print the _items_ in the list, not the list itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = [10,20,30,40]

print("-->".join(str(x) for x in lst))
```

Output:

10-->20-->30-->40

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
print(*lst, sep=' --> ')
```